# Cannot access Transaction in method

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, transactions, transactionscope

I've created an implicit transaction like so:

```
Using ts As New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, New TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0))

MethodA()
ts.Complete()

End Using
```

`MethodA()` in turn calls a number of methods which successfully enlist within the ambient transaction and I can see it:

[image]

however one method (which is 4 deep on the call stack from the creation of `TransactionScope` above) it seems we no longer have access to the ambient transaction:

[image]

It was my belief that this will be available anywhere lower on the stack within the transaction, and is probably is the reason why code within this method has no access to the data within this transaction.

Any ideas why the ambient transaction isn't available?

Comment: Has it been committed prior to geting to this method?

Comment: No - and once the method is done the same transaction is available again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `Transaction` isn't declared, it sounds like that file simply lacks the `using` directive that would bring it into scope. Try setting the watch against

```
System.Transactions.Trasaction.Current.TransactionTraceId.TransactionIdentifier
```

instead, as that will work with or without the `using` directive.

If it were the case that the *ambient transaction was not available*, then `Transaction` would still be fine, but `Transaction.Current` would be `null`. A common reason for this is anything that switches thread, for example `async` code. Knowing what flows over the execution-context is tricky.

Comment: This always happens to me!  I did try that but didn't realise it was `System.Transactions.Tranaction` (transaction twice) so it didn't work.  Seem's it is enlisted within the correct transaction after all.